# 403 Forbidden when using the Repository Search API

Tags: symfony, github-api, ezplatform

I want to list GitHub repositories. I can display JSON in my browser, however when when I try to load an API page, I get a 403 error:

> ```
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:<username>): 
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden`
> ```

My function is as follows:

```
  public function repoListAction() {
    $repositories = json_decode(
      file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:<put your username here>'),
      true
    );

    return $this->render('full/repolist.html.twig', array(
      'repositories' => $repositories,
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub's API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) lists several reasons for a 403 response code. You've likely reached Github's rate limit for unauthenticated queries. You can confirm this by checking the `X-RateLimit-Limit`, `X-RateLimit-Remaining`, and `X-RateLimit-Reset` headers. You could also be missing a `User-Agent` header in your request.

You can confirm the exact issue by checking the body of the response, which will contain details of the exact error and reasoning.